# How to run multiple functions in prallel on same argument. Prettly much Pool but with multiple functions and one argument

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I have a few algorithms which I want to run in parallel. I need their return value and can not modify the functions themself.

That made it hard to use `from multiprocessing import Process` because that why I do not how to get the return value if I can not pass the function a pipe to work with or similar.
Then I tried using `Pool` but then I had to write a wrapper to have one function which takes the argument for the algorithm and then calls the algorithms. But then python is complaining that it can not pickle a local object.

So what can I do.

Comment: Please add your code with expected results.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Create only the arguments outside the process. Create the unpickleable objects inside each process.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the error results from using a non-global function (because of your wrapper) on a platform that uses *spawn* to create new processes, such as Windows.

But your question is somewhat vague and I am not sure why you need a wrapper. Let's suppose you have 3 algorithms that take an `int` and return an `int`. Then why would the following not work?

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool

def algorithm1(x):
    return x ** 2

def algorithm2(x):
    return x ** 3

def algorithm3(x):
    return 2 * x

def main():
    algorithms = (algorithm1, algorithm2, algorithm3)
    pool = Pool(3)
    async_results = [pool.apply_async(algorithm, args=(3,)) for algorithm in algorithms]
    results = [async_result.get() for async_result in async_results]
    print(results)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Prints:

```None
[9, 27, 6]
```